# When to use out parameters in c++, if ever?

Tags: c++

Say my member function needs to return both a `std::vector<std::pair<MyClass,double>>` and a `double`. Both are computed as part of the same algorithm: I need them both returned from the *same* member function. (I.e. I cannot have two separate functions easily; it would require duplicate code and performance overhead.)

I read that it is better to avoid out parameters [in these quidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-out), i.e.:

> F.20: For "out" output values, prefer return values to output
>   parameters.

So my code looks as follow:

```
 std::pair<std::vector<std::pair<MyClass,double>>,double> 
                       computeTransitionsAndCost(double input);
```

(A `std::pair<MyClass,double>` is a transition, hence the name.)

With out parameter, this would be

```
 std::vector<std::pair<MyClass,double>> computeTransitions(double input, double& costOut);
```

In the latter code, it is clearer to the user what the function returns: a list of pairs. But the guidelines are against it, because

> A return value is self-documenting, whereas a & could be either in-out or out-only and is liable to be misused.

Is there any way to adhere to the guidelines and still ensure that it is clear to the user of the code what is represented by the return values?

Comment: primarily opinion based. One case is when the function only optionally returns something and you dont have access to `std::optional` (and you dont want to return a pointer), then you can use a `bool` in addition to signal if the `out` was written. Not a nice pattern at all, but sometimes one has to resort to the less pretty solution

Comment: "_I read that it is better to avoid out parameters_" Where did you read that?

Comment: Opinion -based, but if you can make a function pure, then IMHO you should prefer to do so.

Comment: Why not define a new strongly-named type for your pairs? I think having strongly-named single-purpose primitives is the best option.

Comment: I personally don't like out parameters. So I'd go with `std::pair` or with a simple `struct TransitionsAndCost`

Comment: Those same guidelines that told you to avoid out parameters might have also told you to avoid to use `pair` as a return value, and prefer a dedicated user-defined type with named members

Comment: I would say use typedefs or create your own result structs. Whenever I run into somebody else's code, it takes me a while to figure out what the values in the pairs/tuples are for. A struct is self-documented and lets you put in significant names for each variable.

Comment: `std::pair` is meant for generic code, where you cannot possibly give better names to `first` and `second`. If you can give them meaningful names, then dont use `std::pair`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: In my comment. It is better to avoid out parameters. (Although there could be exceptions to the rule).

Comment: @willem: Consider defining a class/alias for your parameter container. Alternatively, consider templating the computeTransitions functions, and providing an insertion iterator instead of returning a vector. Also, consider `struct WeightedTransition { MyClass transition; double weight; };` or `struct Class WeightedTransition : public MyClass {public: double weight{1}; }`

Comment: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md F.21 states that if you want to return many values, prefer a struct or tuple. It has a pretty good reason. You want to check it out

Comment: When dealing with C++17 you could use std::make_tuple in combination with structured bindings.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: I use the return type to indicate the success of the function, and an out parameter to contain the reason (in text) of why the function didn't succeed.

Comment: @einpoklum "_In my comment. It is better to avoid out parameters._" Which comment of yours? What are the **objective** reasons not to use them? My philosophy is, that every tool has its uses, and that there are no single tool, that solves all problems.

Comment: @user463035818 I agree the question was too opinion-based. I edited to make the issue I need to solve clearer. I think I was struggling with adhering to the guidelines and still produce readable code. I would argue that the question now is less subjective/opinion-based: e.g., naming structs each time creates a lot of structs/files, but the typedef approach improves readability and might work well (I like this latter suggestion and am implementing it right now).

Comment: sorry, but to my understanding what is readable and what not is by definition primarily opinion-based

Comment: @user463035818 : In general, I agree, and my use of the word "readable" is unfortunate. I edited to remove second use of the word readable in the question, to make it more clear what I was looking for when I posted. I am looking for a way to communicate to the user of the function what the return values represent. That is a specific requirement that underlies readability, that perhaps is less subjective.

Comment: @willem: I think it's borderline, and - with a slight edit it should be easily re-openable.

Comment: if you have a set of results to be returned from a function, and if you do not want to pack them on a struct, put ALL of them as parameters after IN parameters. This is more consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not return a composite like follows?

```
struct ComputedTransitions
{
    struct Transition
    {
        MyClass description;
        double weight;
    };
    std::vector<Transition> transitions;
    double cost;
};

ComputedTransitions computeTransitions(double input);
```

This will let you both give meaningful names to the elements of the return value, and put all the related data into one structure.